# How to not show hidefile and hidefolder in ListView in android

Tags: android

I am tired use a fileexplorer when Show a hiddenfile and hiddenfolder but i can not show hidden file and folder please help me.Thanks
in this code

```
for(File ff: dirs){
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified());
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()) {
                        File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles();
                        int buf = 0;
                        if (fbuf != null) {
                            buf = fbuf.length;
                        } else buf = 0;
                        String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                        if (buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                        else num_item = num_item + " items";
//String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                        dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(), num_item, null, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                    }
```